# NetBeans slow load in large project

Tags: performance, netbeans-7

I have a big problem with NetBeans. I'm workig on a project with more than 8,000,000 files ! 
I have added it as a project in NetBeans. But it is really slow to load project files when I start NetBeans.

How can I speed up loading process? Can I config NetBeans to load files progressively or just some specific folders?

My NetBeans version is 7.2

Thank you.

Comment: <troll> Netbeans is slow and stupid, use jetbrain's intellij. </troll>

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for it. Not sure whether it's still working or not. http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand